# ImageView сжимается до нуля, если не выставить размер в сториборде

Tags: swift, uitableview, imageview, storyboard

В сториборде добавляю imageView в ячейку tableView, но если не выставлю высоту или соотношение сторон констрейнтами в сториборде - картинка сжимается до нуля по высоте , а если эту высоту выставлю - не могу изменить её потом в коде, как делать то?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: например создать аутлет для одного из констрейнтов image view, отвечающих за размер, и изменять его свойство `constant`